# Saving multiple HABTM models at the same time

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

Since I can't find a lot of information on *saving two models at the same time* which have a *HABTM relationship*.

I have a subscribe form, to subscribe children online. Parents can enter multiple children and multiple parents at the same time. So a JS can add more textboxes and makes them cake valid (`Model.number.field`)

1. I want to validate the children and the managers (can't use parent model name, so a parent = a manager in this case):

   ```
   if($this->Child->saveAll($this->data['Child'], array('validate' => 'only'))
       && ($this->Manager->saveAll($this->data['Manager'], array('validate' => 'only')))
   )
   {
       debug('form is valid!');
   }
   ```

   This code only works when there is only 1 child and 1 manager (=parent).
2. How do I save these 2 models with a HABTM relationship at the same time?

This is a debug of the value `$this->data`: http://pastebin.com/m6dtBzga

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

For saving multiple records of single model, $data needs to be a numerically indexed array of records like this:

```
Array
(
    [Article] => Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                            [title] => title 1
                        )
            [1] => Array
                (
                            [title] => title 2
                        )
                )
)
```

The command for saving the above $data array would look like this:

```
$this->Article->saveAll($data);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data